# How does $\sum_k \psi_k^*(\vec{r})\psi_k(\vec{r}')=\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$ express the completeness of a basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction

The annihilation field operator is defined as
$$\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})=\sum_k \hat{b}_k \psi_k(\vec{r})$$
Two of these operators satisfy the commutation relations
$$[\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}),\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r}')]=\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$$
$$[\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}),\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}')]=[\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r}),\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r}')]=0$$

My textbook (Nazarov and Danon) states that these can be derived from the definition of the field operator if one notes the *completeness* of the basis which is expressed by
$$\sum_k  \psi_k^*(\vec{r})\psi_k(\vec{r}')=\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')\tag{1}$$
How is the above equation an expression of completeness though? Similarly, given a complete basis $\{\psi_k\}$, how would one go about proving that condition (1) is satisfied for the given complete basis? The way that I would usually express the completeness of a basis is with the relation
$$\sum_k |\psi_k\rangle \langle \psi_k |=\hat{1}$$
But this expression is seemingly nothing alike the expression in eq 1. So how does the condition shown in eq 1 express the completeness of a basis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $$
\sum_k |\psi_k\rangle \langle \psi_k|= {\mathbb I}
$$
then, sandwiching this expression between $\langle x|$ and $|x'\rangle$, we have
$$
\sum_k \langle x|\psi_k\rangle \langle \psi_k|x'\rangle= \langle x|x'\rangle
$$
or, since $\langle x|\psi_k\rangle\equiv \psi_k(x)$ and  $\langle \psi_k|x'\rangle = (\langle x|\psi_k\rangle)^*$, and also  $\langle x|x'\rangle= \delta(x-x')$, your eq 1 becomes
$$
\sum_k \psi_k(x) \psi^*_k(x')= \delta(x-x')
$$

Comment: +1: Lol, I initially thought that this is simply a restatement of the original relation without explaining as to why it implies completeness but apparently that's what the OP is asking for! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! All cleared up now. In line with what Dvij D.C. said though, is there a way to intuitively understand why eq (1) implies completeness? If I imagine the basis set to be the basis of the infinite square well $\{\psi_n\}={\sqrt(2/a)\sin(n\pi x/a)}$, Its not immediately obvious to me that applying eq (1) to this set will yield zero for $x\neq x'$. I can see how the summation over all n will yield infinity when $x=x'$ though.

Comment: Completness is subtle.  See pages 62 onwards in https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf and also later where we consider completness rlations.